# Replace & with &amp; using VBA

Tags: xml, vba

Is there a way to find `&` in the file I am creating with VBA and replace it with `&amp;`?

Here is a short snippet of my code to show how I am creating the file.

```
Open myFile For Output As #1

Print #1, "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"

Print #1, "     <name>" & element & "</name>"

Close #1
```

One of the elements is C&C which is causing my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Print #1, "     <name>" & Replace(element, "&", "&amp;")  & "</name>"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're generating an XML file, unless you're doing something really simple it might be smarter to use an [XML library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of dealing with a million one off little problems like this.

```
'' Add reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0
Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim root As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim reader As New SAXXMLReader60
Dim writer As New MXXMLWriter60

Set root = doc.CreateElement("name")
root.Text = element
doc.appendChild root

Set reader.ContentHandler = writer
writer.Indent = True
reader.Parse doc

Print #1, writer.Output
```

Comment: @ Tmdean I have the feeling I'm going to have to do something like this soon. Where did you learn this magic? I'd like to research some more.

Comment: Hi tbur - I linked to MS's documentation in the answer - that's pretty much all I used to figure it out. I think the library is basically identical to the HTML DOM if you know that already.